# Exiting the GRUB pager

Tags: linux, grub2

I have turned on pager and debug for GRUB in *grub.cfg*:

```
set pager=1
set debug=all
```

Now I'm stuck with long output that GRUB produces. How can I quit that?

I tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>, but nothing worked.

Basically, every key just loads the next page, while <kbd>Enter</kbd> loads one line.

Currently nothing happens at all. I’m not sure if everything is frozen or I’m at the end of the output...

Should I just turn off PC using the physical button?

Comment: It's not an actual solution, so I will add this as a comment. I just ended up powering off PC using physical button.